# How to arrange data in file in Descending order

Tags: linux, bash

I need your help to arrange data in file in Descending order based on cpu value usage.

I run a script which give output file in txt and output contains below data. CPU value comes in column 3. I have tried-  `sort -t: -k2,2rn <filename>`  but it only shows single row with cpu value.

```
Server-DEV~]$   show   cpu
cpu   usage:   16%   used
Server-DEV~]$   show   time
Thu   Sep   26   11:25:06

Server-QA~]$   show   cpu
cpu   usage:   18%   used
 Server-QA~]$   show   time
Thu   Sep   26   11:25:32

Server-PROD~]$   show   cpu   
cpu   usage:   22%   used
 Server-PROD~]$   show   time
Thu   Sep   26   11:25:37

Server-STAGE~]$   show   cpu   
cpu   usage:   11%   used
 Server-STAGE~]$   show   time
Thu   Sep   26   11:26:05
```

Expected like below..

```
Server-PROD~]$   show   cpu   
cpu   usage:   22%   used
 Server-PROD~]$   show   time
Thu   Sep   26   11:25:37

Server-QA~]$   show   cpu
cpu   usage:   18%   used
Server-QA~]$   show   time
Thu   Sep   26   11:25:32

Server-DEV~]$   show   cpu
cpu   usage:   16%   used
Server-DEV~]$   show   time
Thu   Sep   26   11:25:06


Server-STAGE~]$   show   cpu   
cpu   usage:   11%   used
 Server-STAGE~]$   show   time
Thu   Sep   26   11:26:05
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution.  It is not super elegant, and it can probably be all done in 1 awk script, but I feel I put enough time on it already :)

**t.txt**

```
Server-DEV~]$   show   cpu
cpu   usage:   16%   used
Server-DEV~]$   show   time
Thu   Sep   26   11:25:06

Server-QA~]$   show   cpu
cpu   usage:   18%   used
 Server-QA~]$   show   time
Thu   Sep   26   11:25:32

Server-PROD~]$   show   cpu
cpu   usage:   22%   used
 Server-PROD~]$   show   time
Thu   Sep   26   11:25:37

Server-STAGE~]$   show   cpu
cpu   usage:   11%   used
 Server-STAGE~]$   show   time
Thu   Sep   26   11:26:05
```

---

**process.bash**

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -f process.awk t.txt | sort -k5 -n -r | tr '+' '\n' | tr '&' ' '
```

---

**process.awk**

```
/^$/ { print "&" }
!/^$/ { printf("%s+",$0) }
```

---

**Execution**

```
user@host:~/$ ./process.bash
Server-PROD~]$   show   cpu
cpu   usage:   22%   used
 Server-PROD~]$   show   time
Thu   Sep   26   11:25:37
 
Server-QA~]$   show   cpu
cpu   usage:   18%   used
 Server-QA~]$   show   time
Thu   Sep   26   11:25:32
 
Server-DEV~]$   show   cpu
cpu   usage:   16%   used
Server-DEV~]$   show   time
Thu   Sep   26   11:25:06
 
Server-STAGE~]$   show   cpu
cpu   usage:   11%   used
 Server-STAGE~]$   show   time
Thu   Sep   26   11:26:05
```

---

**Explanations**

1. `awk` replaces empty lines with char `&`.
2. `awk` replaces all new lines with a `+`.
3. Step 2 puts each paragraph into 1 line.
4. `sort` can then be used to sort the 4 lines on field no.5, which is the cpu usage % value you want to sort on.
5. Then replace the '+' back to new lines.
6. Finally replace the `&` to 1 space, to get the empty lines back.

So at step 3, your data looks like:

```
Server-PROD~]$   show   cpu+cpu   usage:   22%   used+ Server-PROD~]$   show   time+Thu   Sep   26   11:25:37+&
Server-QA~]$   show   cpu+cpu   usage:   18%   used+ Server-QA~]$   show   time+Thu   Sep   26   11:25:32+&
Server-DEV~]$   show   cpu+cpu   usage:   16%   used+Server-DEV~]$   show   time+Thu   Sep   26   11:25:06+&
Server-STAGE~]$   show   cpu+cpu   usage:   11%   used+ Server-STAGE~]$   show   time+Thu   Sep   26   11:26:05+
```